# I want to enlist total folders in my list box and then open selected folder

Tags: php

I am trying to open a folder by this command.

```
system("folder_path");
```

But my folder is not opening.
I am using php.

Comment: Please add much, much more detail about what you mean by "open a folder" - you mean in a GUI? Where, on the user's machine or your own? What platform is your PHP running on? Etc. etc.

Comment: Also, please use the search function. Chances are, some already asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love Google - http://in.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
And http://in.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

Comment: When did this google thing come out?

Comment: it is in my browser, it asks me what I am looking for and searches things for me, its awesome, do you want it?